# Why so high values of noise température of a spectrum analyser?

Tags: noise, spectrum-analyzer

We know that the displayed average noise level(DANL) and noise figure(NF) of a spectrum analyser is given by the following equation:

\begin{equation}
NF_{} = _{L}[dBm] + 174dBm −10 \cdot log_{10}(RW/1)  +2.5 dB
\end{equation}

where RBW is a resolution bandwidth 2.5 dB is some constant coming from a detector (anyway it is not clear for me, but it is a detail for now). By the way there is no signal sent to analyzer in the experiment.

So what I see that for some spectrum analyzer the DANL is about -90 dBm for RBW = 2.4 MHz, so I get the value of NF = 22dBm. Then from the NF equation
\begin{equation}
T = T_0 (10^{NF}-1) = 46500 K
\end{equation}

So the question is, where is a catch, is it OK to have such an astronomic values? Could it come from all the electronics of the spectrum analyzer?
Another question, what is the origin of the $NF_{SA}$  formula? I can understand that 174 dBm and  the term of RBW comes from the noise of a resistor at 300K, but the term of $ L_{DANL}$ is not clear for me, is this just a definition

Comment: A noise figure of 22 dB is pretty standard. It's probably in the specifications of the unit too. What were you expecting?

Comment: @tomnexus I have a budget SA and it says DANL is -165 dBm/Hz, I'm not sure if this compares to 22 dB or not.

Comment: @tomnexus, the temperature converted from the NF just looks to big comparing to 300K of room temperature

Answer (score 2):

A noise figure of 22 dB is pretty normal for a spectrum analyser.

Expressed as a noise temperature it looks like a large number, but there are many equations which yield unexpected and large numbers. Try calculating the noise temperature of a transmitter for example! Noise temperatures are convenient when they're below room temperature, and when you have other Kelvin-denominated temperatures like sky temperature. dB would work too but the numbers are small and don't add intuitively.

Noise figure can be improved by putting a high gain, low noise amplifier in front of the more noisy input. These amplifiers bring a big compromise - they are sensitive but easily overloaded by all the strong signals out there - FM broadcast, TV, cellphones. A spectrum analyser doesn't start with a low noise amplifier, it starts with an attenuator, mixer and a filter, hence the higher noise figure. See how every second question about SDRs asks about some unidentified strong signal that can be found every 5 MHz right across the band. A spectrum analyser is mostly immune to this, you can look at quite weak signals near to strong ones. And receive chains that depend on a low noise preamplifier, like GPS, have a narrow filter before the preamplifier, to prevent any of the strong signals from interfering.

On your question about $L_{DANL}$ - this isn't so much a fixed parameter of the instrument, as simply the input-referred (internal) noise of the receiver, displayed as a trace.

If you want to know where the correction factor comes from, and many other useful facts about noise and how to measure it, I recommend reading the whole of the **[Agilent Application Note AN 1303](https://www.google.com/search?q=Agilent%20application%20note%20AN%201303%20pdf)**. It's no longer on their website but there are many copies floating around. Keysight now seems to offer [AN 5966 4008](https://www.keysight.com/ca/en/assets/7018-06765/application-notes/5966-4008.pdf) which covers the same subject but more aimed at all-digital instruments. It's not as easy or quick to understand.